# How can I establish a connection with Rocketly with Follow Up Boss (Fub)?

Tags: automation, integration, sites

I'm trying to integrate Rocketly into my project, but I'm unsure how to establish a connection with their API. Could someone provide a clear example or guide on how to integrate Rocketly with Follow Up Boss?